# Wrong ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to display an error message if the fetch array result from ajax page contains anything, and do nothing if the array result is empty. My jQuery is not returning correct value. Please help me to solve this. Here is my jQuery ajax code.

```
function getmsg(obj){
    //var invoc_num = $("#inv_num").val();
    //alert(invoc_num); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_invoc_num.php',
        data: "invoc_num="+ invoc_num,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            var data = data.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
            alert(data);
            if(data == "ok"){                                       
            }
            else{       
                $('#inv_msg').html("invoice number exists..!");     
            }                   
        } 
    });
}
```

My php code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['msg_agency_code'])){    
    $agency_code=$_SESSION['msg_agency_code'];
}

$invoc_num=$_POST['invoc_num'];

echo $CheckInvoicenum = $timesheetObj>CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num);
if (empty($CheckInvoicenum)){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "exists";
}
```

For every input for invoc_num i am getting ok as result.

Comment: Firstly remove `async: false`; it's terrible practice. Secondly as you're returning a plaintext response, make sure there's no whitespace: `data.trim() == "ok"`. Thirdly don't return a plaintext response. Use JSON, or XML or literally anything else which has a formal structure.

Comment: what is this line? `echo $CheckInvoicenum = 
$timesheetObj>CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num);` are you sure `echo` should be there?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok.thankyou for the advice..

Comment: @LiamG I am using object oriented concept.$timesheetObj->CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoice_num) is my query. I put echo there just to check if it returns anyhing.there is data.This is the query-                                                                    
    SELECT * FROM ss_invoice1 WHERE created='1' AND 
    invoc_num='$invoc_num' AND agency_code='$agency_code'

Answer (score 0):

Check this particular line from your php code

> echo $CheckInvoicenum = $timesheetObj>CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num);

It probably needs to be this.

> $CheckInvoicenum = $timesheetObj->CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num);

Also, your MySQL query is always going to return empty if no `$agency_code` value is passed (or is always empty) and no records in the database match this. You may want to use the `$agency_code` variable in the query, only if it is not empty.

You may also want to ensure that your database call returns the coreect value.
To verify this, take care of the following -

> a) Select only the columns that you need from the select query.
>   b) in the return statement do `return $result[0];` if you need the first  column's value

Comment: I have checked,agency_code and invoc_num always has a value.And I have removed echo from my line.Still no change in the result.still getting same response for both not empty result and empty result..!@DeadLock

Comment: Did you update your code to include the misson '-' while invoking `$timesheetObj->CheckInvoicebyId` ?

Comment: $CheckInvoicenum = $timesheetOb->CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num); yes.@DeadLock

Comment: What is the value of `$CheckInvoicenum`? do a `var_dump($CheckInvoicenum)`. Also, have you initialized the `$timesheetObj` object?

Comment: Hi I var_dumped it and I am getting array(0) for any input query.but the query is correct andworking in phpmyadmin ;and Yes,I have initialized the timesheetObj object in another page and included the page in this phpfile@DeadLock

Comment: Then you need to show us the `CheckInvoicebyId` function. my guess is you might be returning the mysql array response directly without picking the column value.

Comment: This is CheckInvoiucebyId function,                                                                 
                                                                                                                       
        function CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ss_invoice1 WHERE created='1' AND invoc_num='$invoc_num' AND agency_code='$agency_code'";
 $results = $this->db->fetchArray($this->db->query($sql));
 $this->db->close();
 return $results;
 }@DeadLock

Comment: 2 things - a) select only the columns that you need from the select query. b) in the return statement do `return $result[0];` if you need the first column's value.

Comment: made the changes but that didnt make any difference,now the function is  function CheckInvoicebyId($agency_code,$invoc_num){
 echo $sql = "SELECT invoc_num FROM ss_invoice1 WHERE created='1' AND invoc_num='$invoc_num' AND agency_code='$agency_code'";
 $results = $this->db->fetchArray($this->db->query($sql));
 $this->db->close();
 return $results['invoc_num'];
 }@DeadLock

Comment: Why do you keep adding echo everywhere? The moment you add an echo and it prints something, that string is going to get sent back as the ajax response. What is the value of `$CheckInvoicenum` after this change? What does the var_dump of it print?

Comment: array(0){ } is the value of $CheckInvoicenum.I have removed all the echo's.@DeadLock

Comment: var_dump($results)? Does it print the values you need?

Comment: No.Its not printing correct result.but the query is correct.When I call the query fuction using object its not returning correct result.@DeadLock

Comment: Sorry guys.And finally i figured out ,it was a careless mistake i made.I didn't opened mysql connection...!!!!!.You were all so helping.